# Kernel panic in com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2

Tags: kernel-panic

It's happening every once in a while that I get a kernel panic like the following:

```
Anonymous UUID:       298497E3-67C5-3C3E-49A8-F58D0EF87D19

Wed Sep  5 14:31:51 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800d78776f): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f901a34d7, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000018, CR3: 0x00000000118c2000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff803a4049a0, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0xffffff91f9cf3d70
RSP: 0xffffff91f9cf3d50, RBP: 0xffffff91f9cf3d50, RSI: 0xffffff8047b059b8, RDI: 0xffffff91f9cf3d68
R8:  0xffffff8047b0581c, R9:  0x0000000000000001, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000001
R12: 0xffffff8047b059b8, R13: 0xffffff8047b05680, R14: 0xffffff803a42f800, R15: 0xffffff91f9cf3d68
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff7f901a34d7, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000018, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91f9cf3820 : 0xffffff800d66c1c6 
0xffffff91f9cf3870 : 0xffffff800d795274 
0xffffff91f9cf38b0 : 0xffffff800d787544 
0xffffff91f9cf3920 : 0xffffff800d61e1e0 
0xffffff91f9cf3940 : 0xffffff800d66bc3c 
0xffffff91f9cf3a70 : 0xffffff800d66b9fc 
0xffffff91f9cf3ad0 : 0xffffff800d78776f 
0xffffff91f9cf3c40 : 0xffffff800d61e1e0 
0xffffff91f9cf3c60 : 0xffffff7f901a34d7 
0xffffff91f9cf3d50 : 0xffffff7f9019fe22 
0xffffff91f9cf3dc0 : 0xffffff7f900d01e2 
0xffffff91f9cf3de0 : 0xffffff7f900d22b7 
0xffffff91f9cf3e10 : 0xffffff7f900c036a 
0xffffff91f9cf3e80 : 0xffffff7f90146ba3 
0xffffff91f9cf3ea0 : 0xffffff7f900bc41c 
0xffffff91f9cf3ed0 : 0xffffff800dc99785 
0xffffff91f9cf3f30 : 0xffffff800dc97ef2 
0xffffff91f9cf3f70 : 0xffffff800dc9752c 
0xffffff91f9cf3fa0 : 0xffffff800d61d557 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7f9008f000->0xffffff7f90127fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[4FAE8181-B0B4-3A30-B0F3-77F48D2486E5]@0xffffff7f8e466000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.15)[37BCC686-AF99-3381-AC4F-E54A347E0F40]@0xffffff7f8f180000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7f8df34000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7f8e4d7000
         com.apple.GeForce(10.3.2)[5FE0FEE7-0291-309C-B94E-ED28C718384E]@0xffffff7f90138000->0xffffff7f901d3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AEA4C7F5-CCB0-338B-B471-CF28A9792522]@0xffffff7f8df34000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(519.20)[64AB0898-0DF1-32DF-850A-8840C3478439]@0xffffff7f8e52d000
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.3.2)[6DE4BC26-EEC1-379B-AD41-532FB0A529CD]@0xffffff7f8e549000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.20)[0E507098-E375-39B7-9AE2-AFF2C7A5D961]@0xffffff7f8e4d7000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.26)[AE312652-F3AF-3BFD-AEFF-FE4CCCC33BA9]@0xffffff7f9008f000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
17G65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1AE5ACFD-3B6F-3D74-AD52-31F1430DBC6F
Kernel slide:     0x000000000d400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800d500000
System model name: iMac13,1 (Mac-00BE6ED71E35EB86)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 191429330875612
last loaded kext at 191330259745904: com.apple.filesystems.apfs 748.51.0 (addr 0xffffff7f910eb000, size 999424)
last unloaded kext at 191391590936425: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7f910e3000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.1.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.1.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.1.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.1.30
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   92
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.3
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.37
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.52
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.52
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.2
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1240.19.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1404.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  205
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 680.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   680.15
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.52
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.2
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.20.13
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.52
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.20
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.26
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.15
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.20.13
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.20
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.7f10
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.7f10
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    546.50.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.70.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.70.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.60.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    680.15
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1

EOF

System Profile:
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 23.4
Boot Volume File System Type: hfs
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: STU-430
USB Device: PTZ-431W
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST1000LM024, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM128E, 121.33 GB
Model: iMac13,1, BootROM IM131.0115.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.9f5
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M, PCIe
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF4), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.18.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
```

I also run EtreCheck and this is the report:

```
EtreCheck version: 4.3.6 (4D041)
Report generated: 2018-09-05 15:02:07
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 17:10
Performance: Poor

Problem: Computer is restarting
Description:
macOS is going into kernel panic

Major Issues:
Anything that appears on this list needs immediate attention.

Unsigned files - There are unsigned software installed that could be adware and should be reviewed.
Kernel panics - This system has experienced kernel panics. This could be a sign of hardware failure.
Poor performance - EtreCheck report took over 10 minutes to run. This is very unusual.
Heavy CPU usage - Some processes are using an unusually high amount of CPU.

Minor Issues:
These issues do not need immediate attention but they may indicate future problems.

Heavy network usage - This machine has recently restarted and has high network usage.
Clean up - There are orphan files that could be removed.
System modifications - There are a large number of system modifications running in the background.

Hardware Information:
iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012)
iMac Model: iMac13,1
1 2,7 GHz Intel Core i5 (i5-3330S) CPU: 4-core
16 GB RAM - Upgradeable
BANK 0/DIMM0 - 8 GB DDR3 1600 ok
BANK 1/DIMM0 - 8 GB DDR3 1600 ok

Video Information:
NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M - VRAM: 512 MB
iMac 1920 x 1080

Drives:
disk0 - APPLE SSD SM128E 121.33 GB (Solid State - TRIM: Yes)
Internal SATA 6 Gigabit Serial ATA
disk0s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
disk0s2 [Core Storage Container] 120.99 GB
disk2 - Macintosh HD (Journaled HFS+) [Fusion Drive] 1.11 TB
disk0s3 - B*******X [Recovery] 134 MB

disk1 - APPLE HDD ST1000LM024 1.00 TB (Mechanical)
Internal SATA 3 Gigabit Serial ATA
disk1s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
disk1s2 [Core Storage Container] 999.35 GB
disk2 - Macintosh HD (Journaled HFS+) [Fusion Drive] 1.11 TB
disk1s3 - Recovery HD (Journaled HFS+) [Recovery] 650 MB

disk3 - Disk Image 11.24 TB (Disk Image)
External Disk Image
disk3s1 - EFI (MS-DOS FAT32) [EFI] 210 MB
disk3s2 - B********************e (Case-Sensitive Journaled HFS+) 11.24 TB

Mounted Volumes:
disk2 - Macintosh HD [Fusion Drive] 1.11 TB (38.92 GB free)
Journaled HFS+
Mount point: /

disk3s2 - B********************e 11.24 TB (549.49 GB free)
Case-Sensitive Journaled HFS+
Mount point: /Volumes/B********************e

Network:
Interface en1: Wi-Fi
Interface en0: Ethernet
One IPv4 address
Interface en4: Bluetooth PAN
Interface en5: iPhone
Interface en6: iPad
iCloud Quota: 2.29 GB available

System Software:
macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65)
Time since boot: Less than an hour
System Load: 3.50 (1 min ago) 4.64 (5 min ago) 3.87 (15 min ago)

Configuration Files:
/etc/hosts - Count: 77

Security:
System  Status
Gatekeeper  Mac App Store and identified developers
System Integrity Protection Enabled

Unsigned Files:
Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Java Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Java Updater -bgcheck
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.epicgames.launcher.plist
Executable: /Applications/Epic Games Launcher.app/Contents/MacOS/EpicGamesLauncher-Mac-Shipping -silent
Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.brother.LOGINserver.plist
Executable: /Library/Printers/Brother/Utilities/Server/LOGINserver.app/Contents/MacOS/LOGINserver
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
Executable: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/Helper-Tool
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.jetbrains.AppCode.BridgeService.plist
Executable: /Applications/AppCode.app/Contents/bin/Build.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Bridge.framework/Versions/A/Resources/BridgeService
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist
Executable: ~/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/steamclean Public
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist
Executable: /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/vboxwebsrv
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.crashreportsender.symbolicator.plist
Executable: ~/QuincyKit/symbolicate.sh
Details: Domain name invalid - possibly adware
Launchd: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.leapmotion.Leap-Motion.plist
Executable: '/Applications/Leap Motion.app' '/Applications/Leap Motion.app' --args --autolaunch
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist
Executable: /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Library/LaunchServices/com.skype.skype.shareagent.bundle/Contents/MacOS/com.skype.skype.shareagent
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/it.altralogica.symbolicatecrash.plist
Executable: ~/QuincyKit/symbolicate.sh
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Executable: /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcscouch.plist
Executable: /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/CurrentXcodeSymlink/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcscouch/startcouch.sh
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.intel.haxm.plist
Executable: /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/haxm_start.sh
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Executable: /usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
Executable: /bin/bash '/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/jenkins-runner.sh'
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK
Launchd: /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
Executable: /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
Details: Exact match found in the whitelist - probably OK

Kernel Extensions:
/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox
[Loaded] VBoxDrv.kext (Oracle America, Inc., 5.1.30)
[Loaded] VBoxNetAdp.kext (Oracle America, Inc., 5.1.30)
[Loaded] VBoxNetFlt.kext (Oracle America, Inc., 5.1.30)
[Loaded] VBoxUSB.kext (Oracle America, Inc., 5.1.30)

/Library/Extensions
[Not Loaded] FTDIKext.kext (Wacom Technology Corp., 1.0 - SDK 10.11)
[Loaded] intelhaxm.kext (Intel Corporation Apps, 6.2.1 - SDK 10.9)
[Loaded] iShowU Audio Capture.kext (Shiny White Box Limited, 1.0.1 - SDK 10.9)

/System/Library/Extensions
[Not Loaded] Wacom Tablet.kext (Wacom Technology Corp., Wacom Tablet 6.3.9-3 - SDK 10.9)

System Launch Agents:
[Not Loaded]    9 Apple tasks
[Loaded]    173 Apple tasks
[Running]   111 Apple tasks
[Other] One Apple task

System Launch Daemons:
[Not Loaded]    33 Apple tasks
[Loaded]    178 Apple tasks
[Running]   127 Apple tasks

Launch Agents:
[Running]   com.leapmotion.Leap-Motion.plist (? 6d55023b - installed 2015-08-31)
[Other] com.paragon.updater.plist (? af829e83 - installed 2013-07-29)
[Loaded]    com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist (? 587c5c5d - installed 2018-07-07)
[Not Loaded]    com.adobe.AdobeCreativeCloud.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-11-08)
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.agent.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-06-07)
[Running]   com.brother.LOGINserver.plist (? a1772de2 - installed 2015-03-12)
[Loaded]    com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2018-08-28)
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.status.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-06-07)
[Other] com.adobe.ARMDCHelper.cc24aef4a1b90ed56a725c38014c95072f92651fb65e1bf9c8e43c37a23d420d.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-02-15)
[Loaded]    com.google.keystone.agent.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2018-07-19)
[Not Loaded]    com.teamviewer.teamviewer_desktop.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2017-05-23)
[Not Loaded]    com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist (? ffb65062 - installed 2018-02-26)
[Running]   com.malwarebytes.mbam.frontend.agent.plist (Malwarebytes Corporation - installed 2018-08-06)
[Loaded]    com.crashreportsender.symbolicator.plist (? dbf22777 - installed 2012-05-10)
[Running]   com.wacom.wacomtablet.plist (Wacom Technology Corp. - installed 2015-12-16)
[Not Loaded]    com.teamviewer.teamviewer.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2017-05-23)
[Not Loaded]    com.adobe.GC.Invoker-1.0.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-06-01)

Launch Daemons:
[Running]   com.malwarebytes.mbam.rtprotection.daemon.plist (Malwarebytes Corporation - installed 2018-08-06)
[Loaded]    com.adobe.fpsaud.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-12-15)
[Running]   com.leapmotion.leapd.plist (Leap Motion, Inc. - installed 2015-08-31)
[Not Loaded]    org.macports.rsyncd.plist (? 0 - installed )
[Running]   com.malwarebytes.mbam.settings.daemon.plist (Malwarebytes Corporation - installed 2018-08-06)
[Loaded]    com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-02-15)
[Loaded]    com.adobe.acc.installer.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2017-11-08)
[Not Loaded]    org.virtualbox.startup.plist (? 700b9385 - installed 2017-12-01)
[Running]   org.jenkins-ci.plist (? 5cdd47ef - installed 2017-10-03)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcscouch.plist (? b9fca469 - installed 2017-09-21)
[Loaded]    com.google.keystone.daemon.plist (Google, Inc. - installed 2018-07-19)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcsd.plist (Apple - installed 2018-06-05)
[Running]   com.bjango.istatmenus.daemon.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2018-06-07)
[Loaded]    com.shinywhitebox.iShowUAudioDaemon.plist (Shiny White Box Limited - installed 2015-05-29)
[Running]   com.adobe.agsservice.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-06-01)
[Not Loaded]    com.barebones.textwrangler.plist (? d1ef2342 - installed 2012-03-20)
[Loaded]    com.screenhero.SHAccessibilityHelper.plist (Screenhero, Inc. - installed 2013-11-27)
[Loaded]    com.BlueStacks.AppPlayer.bstservice_helper.plist (BlueStack Systems, Inc. - installed 2016-07-14)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcsredis.plist (Apple - installed 2018-06-05)
[Loaded]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2018-08-28)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcsd.worker.plist (Apple - installed 2018-06-05)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcscontrol.plist (Apple - installed 2018-06-05)
[Not Loaded]    com.teamviewer.teamviewer_service.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2017-05-23)
[Loaded]    com.teamviewer.Helper.plist (TeamViewer GmbH - installed 2017-05-23)
[Loaded]    com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist (? e3fefdd2 - installed 2018-07-07)
[Loaded]    com.apple.installer.osmessagetracing.plist (Apple - installed 2018-07-04)
[Loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2015-08-15)
[Loaded]    com.wacom.displayhelper.plist (Apple - installed 2018-07-04)
[Loaded]    com.malwarebytes.HelperTool.plist (Malwarebytes Corporation - installed 2017-10-30)
[Loaded]    com.bjango.istatmenus.installerhelper.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2017-10-31)
[Loaded]    com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-02-15)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcsnginx.plist (Apple - installed 2018-06-05)
[Loaded]    com.intel.haxm.plist (? 42f307e7 - installed 2017-08-21)
[Running]   com.adobe.agmservice.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-06-01)

User Launch Agents:
[Loaded]    it.altralogica.symbolicatecrash.plist (? 0 - installed 2012-05-10)
[Loaded]    com.dropbox.DropboxMacUpdate.agent.plist (Dropbox, Inc. - installed 2018-08-27)
[Loaded]    com.valvesoftware.steamclean.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-04-05)
[Not Loaded]    org.virtualbox.vboxwebsrv.plist (? 0 - installed 2017-12-01)
[Not Loaded]    com.adobe.GC.Invoker-1.0.plist (Adobe Systems, Inc. - installed 2018-06-01)
[Other] homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-06-18)
[Not Loaded]    homebrew.mxcl.boot2docker.plist (? 0 - installed )
[Running]   com.spotify.webhelper.plist (Spotify - installed 2017-08-29)
[Not Loaded]    com.apple.xcsbuilder.plist (Apple - installed 2018-06-05)
[Loaded]    com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist (? 0 - installed 2017-11-24)
[Running]   com.epicgames.launcher.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-08-30)
[Other] com.github.facebook.watchman.plist (? 0 - installed 2016-11-15)
[Running]   homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-06-18)
[Loaded]    com.jetbrains.AppCode.BridgeService.plist (? 0 - installed 2018-03-16)

User Login Items:
Dropbox Applicazione (Dropbox, Inc. - installed 2018-08-29)
(/Applications/Dropbox.app)
Alfred 3 Applicazione (Running with Crayons Ltd - installed 2018-08-29)
(/Applications/Alfred 3.app)
Android File Transfer Agent Applicazione (? - installed 2012-10-15)
(~/Library/Application Support/Google/Android File Transfer/Android File Transfer Agent.app)

Internet Plug-ins:
MeetingJoinPlugin: (installed 2017-08-03)
o1dbrowserplugin: (installed 2015-12-17)
WacomNetscape: (installed 2012-01-20)
Unity Web Player: (installed 2016-05-08)
WacomTabletPlugin: (installed 2015-12-16)
AdobeAAMDetect: (installed 2017-11-08)
FlashPlayer-10.6: (installed 2018-01-24)
AdobePDFViewerNPAPI: (installed 2018-08-27)
Silverlight: (installed 2012-10-25)
QuickTime Plugin: (installed 2018-07-19)
Flash Player: (installed 2018-01-24)
googletalkbrowserplugin: (installed 2015-12-11)
SharePointBrowserPlugin: (installed 2015-09-01)
AdobePDFViewer: (installed 2018-08-27)
iPhotoPhotocast: (installed 2012-11-05)
JavaAppletPlugin: (installed 2018-07-20)

Safari Extensions:
AdBlock.safariextz - BetaFish, Inc. - https://getadblock.com (installed 2018-08-29)
OpenIE.safariextz - Parallels - http://www.parallels.com (installed 2013-10-23)

3rd Party Preference Panes:
AirServer (installed 2012-03-22)
Flash Player (installed 2017-12-15)
Java (installed 2018-07-20)
WacomTablet (installed 2015-12-16)

Time Machine:
Skip System Files: No
Mobile backups: No
Auto backup: Yes
Volumes being backed up:
Macintosh HD: Disk size: 1.11 TB - Disk used: 1.07 TB
Destinations:
b****p [Network] (Last used)
Total size: 11.24 TB
Total number of backups: 98
Oldest backup: 2017-02-23 23:30:25
Last backup: 2018-09-05 13:51:43

Top Processes by CPU:
Process (count) Source  % of CPU    Location
diagnosticd Apple   115 
Console Apple   79  
system_profiler (2) Apple   77  
trustd (3)  Apple   29  
mdworker (3)    Apple   17  

Top Processes by Memory:
Process (count) Source  RAM usage   Location
qemu-system-x86_64  ?   1.17 GB ~/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64
kernel_task Apple   1.16 GB 
VisualStudio    ?   1.13 GB /Applications/Visual Studio.app
Safari  Apple   750 MB  
com.apple.WebKit.WebContent (2) Apple   394 MB  

Top Processes by Network Use:
Process Source  Input   Output  Location
kernel_task Apple   1.14 GB 607 MB  
com.apple.WebKit.Networking Apple   1 MB    2 MB    
mDNSResponder   Apple   1 MB    344 KB  
Dropbox ?   348 KB  389 KB  /Applications/Dropbox.app
java    Apple   615 KB  7 KB    

Top Processes by Energy Use:
Process (count) Source  Energy (0-100)  Location
qemu-system-x86_64  ?   31  ~/android-sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64
VisualStudio    ?   7   /Applications/Visual Studio.app
mdworker (3)    Apple   5   
mono64 (2)  ?   5   /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/bin
WindowServer    Apple   5   

Virtual Memory Information:
Available RAM   3.84 GB
Free RAM    31 MB
Used RAM    12.16 GB
Cached files    3.81 GB
Swap Used   0 B


Diagnostics Information (past 7 days):
2018-09-05 14:31:52 Kernel Panic
3rd party kernel extensions:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.1.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.1.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.1.30
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.1.30
com.shinywhitebox.iShowU-Audio-Capture  1.0.1


End of report
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I get a very similar error on my iMac 2014. Comparing the loaded kexts between our two systems, it could possibly be the LeapMotion device connected. I'm going to try to disconnect mine and see if it fixes it.

```
Anonymous UUID:       F36129E9-69E1-B321-06F7-0519199C40B7

Mon Sep 24 20:12:43 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801f8d87bd): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801f8bbdda, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000000009a0008, CR3: 0x000000066737110a, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x000000000086f5fe, RBX: 0x000000000060d87a, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000020
RSP: 0xffffff83cf4f3b10, RBP: 0xffffff83cf4f3b90, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff804fac7f40, R9:  0x0000000000000020, R10: 0xffffff802009cc30, R11: 0x000ffffffffff000
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x00000000009a0000, R14: 0xffffff804fac7f40, R15: 0xffffff83cf4f3ba0
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff801f8bbdda, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00000000009a0008, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 2, VF: 5

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff83cf4f35e0 : 0xffffff801f7aca1d 
0xffffff83cf4f3630 : 0xffffff801f8e6b13 
0xffffff83cf4f3670 : 0xffffff801f8d859a 
0xffffff83cf4f36e0 : 0xffffff801f759ca0 
0xffffff83cf4f3700 : 0xffffff801f7ac437 
0xffffff83cf4f3820 : 0xffffff801f7ac283 
0xffffff83cf4f3890 : 0xffffff801f8d87bd 
0xffffff83cf4f3a00 : 0xffffff801f759ca0 
0xffffff83cf4f3a20 : 0xffffff801f8bbdda 
0xffffff83cf4f3b90 : 0xffffff801f861778 
0xffffff83cf4f3be0 : 0xffffff801f875789 
0xffffff83cf4f3c20 : 0xffffff801f8770a1 
0xffffff83cf4f3c50 : 0xffffff801f858088 
0xffffff83cf4f3cc0 : 0xffffff801f85681b 
0xffffff83cf4f3d10 : 0xffffff801f857c41 
0xffffff83cf4f3d40 : 0xffffff801f856dab 
0xffffff83cf4f3d80 : 0xffffff801f8424a9 
0xffffff83cf4f3ed0 : 0xffffff801f849842 
0xffffff83cf4f3f10 : 0xffffff801fcc1651 
0xffffff83cf4f3f40 : 0xffffff801fdb5b7b 
0xffffff83cf4f3fa0 : 0xffffff801f75a466 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
18A389

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.0.0: Wed Aug 22 20:13:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4903.201.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DF83AD37-501E-3B4F-B1F0-04F3AC90FE35
Kernel slide:     0x000000001f400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801f600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801f500000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-42FD25EABCABB274)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 956216664080873
last loaded kext at 679881086497924: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7fa27eb000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 680001321002457: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7fa27eb000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.vmware.kext.vmx86   0947.23.07
com.vmware.kext.vmnet   0947.23.07
com.vmware.kext.vmci    90.8.1
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.22.18
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.22.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.fileutil  1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.8f6
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.41
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   12.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.10
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    212
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  12.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.0.7
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.200.129
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.200.2
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   190
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs 1.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.22.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 700.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   700.7
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    527
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.22.9
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.22.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    400.24
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.5
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.8f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.8f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.8f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.8f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.200.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    700.7
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: iMac15,1, BootROM IM151.0217.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 4 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.22f16
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M290X, AMD Radeon R9 M290X, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.8f6, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: JMicron
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: Leap Motion Controller
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Usb Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

Comment: I have uninstalled the Leap Motion driver and updated to Mojave yesterday . So far no glitches yet.